# What's the best way to find candidates for UX Designer?

Tags: jobs, ux-field, hiring

Beyond the obvious (posting on LinkedIn, Craigslist), what techniques have you found to be the most successful in finding good UX candidates to hire?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to try job listings that are made for a UX/IxD/HCI audience (eg. http://www.authenticjobs.com/, http://jobs.boxesandarrows.com/, http://iainstitute.org/jobboard/).

If you're looking to hire someone in a specific area, find local interest groups (eg. [local IxDA groups](http://www.ixda.org/)) and try to post your job there.

Further, you can try to seed your job posting via Twitter (eg. through @IA_UXJOBS, @UIDesignJobs).